# What kind of shape should I feed into this placeholder in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,],name="input_y")
```

[None,] is weird and I don't know what kind of shape of data should I  feed in and I get error like this:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 1999) for Tensor 'input_y:0', which has shape '(?,)'
```

Comment: I tried (4,1) and (1,4), both of them are error. I have no idea of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-D array is OK, whatever length is.

If length is constrained, `None` should be replaced with a fixed number.
Normaly, a Tensor has a `shape` attribute and `get_shape()` method to get the static shape.

Details can be found at official tutorial like https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensors and https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/shapes

Comment: Thanks. However, as I said above, I tried 1-D array and I thought it would be fine, but it threw an error as: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 1) for Tensor 'input_y:0', which has shape '(?,)' I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: As Traceback said, you feed a `(64, 1)` array, it's a 2-D array instead of 1-D (`(64, )`for your example). you should flatten or reshape your data to (64, 1) firstly.

Comment: `a = np.arange(64).reshape(64, 1)` is **2-D** array, but `b = np.arange(64)` is **1-D** array. as i say,  `c = a.flatten()` is **1-D** array